# Python - Variable assignment & reassignment - what happened to X here?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, variable-assignment

I am working a puzzle regarding variables and cannot figure out how my variable changes from 1 to 0 in the process below:

```
x = 1
y = 0

# first assignment
x = x^y
print(f'x value is {x} after reassignment')
# x value is 1 after reassignment

# second assignment
y = y^x
print(f'y value is {y} after reassignment')
# y value is 1 after reassignment

print(f'{y} = {y} ^ {x}')
# returns 1 = 1 ^ 1

# x value is now 1 but somehow ZERO after the assignment below
x = x^y   
print(f'{x} = {y} ^ {x} how did x become zero from this assignment?')
# returns 0 = 1 ^ 0
```

I want to understand how that x became zero.  thank you!

Comment: It's pretty simple: `1 ^ 1 == 0`. The bigger picture is that this type of repeated assignment is an old trick for swapping two integer values without a temporary variable.

Comment: `1 ^ 1` is not `1` - you're mixing up the pre- and post-assignment values of `y` in `f'{y} = {y} ^ {x}'`.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the operator that you are using. In Python the `^` operator is Bitwise XOR. As such `1 ^ 1 = 0`. Your assumption that `1 = 1 ^ 1` is incorrect. If you were attempting to raise to a power, use `x**y`.

Comment: This is exactly what I overlooked!  thank you so much!